# Do I need RAID 1 when setting up Btrfs on Linux?

Tags: linux, debian, raid, btrfs, ssd

I would like to install Debian setting up my disk using Btrfs.

I have read on the Debian documentation (https://wiki.debian.org/Btrfs) on the recommendations section, it says that I should use at least 2 equal partitions in Raid 1. I understand that this is to have corruption data protection.

This will be for a desktop, used mainly for programming. Also I would need to set up encryption.

I only have one physical SSD, in this case is it still recommended to have RAID 1?

If you have suggestions regarding setting up Btrfs, please also comment.

Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps someone can add more to this if I'm missing something, but it only recommends RAID 1. It's up to you. Another note is that RAID 1 doesn't protect from corruption. In fact, because the drives are mirrored, the corruption is likely to be written to both.

Comment: @NasirRiley I mean corruption, like a bad block, if there's a bad block in a file then the file could be correct by looking in it's copy on the RAID, this is what I imagine it does.

Comment: The drives are mirrored. If the file has a bad block or the checksum is off or anything else, then it's going to be written to both disks and both files will have it. Regardless of the level, the purpose of RAID isn't to protect data but to protect against downtime.

Comment: @Nasir Riley  He only has 1 drive so why even use raid?

Comment: @MarkScheck That's why I've stated that RAID 1 is recommended and not required. I'm just clarifying that it doesn't protect against data corruption.

Comment: @MarkScheck But it seems that RAID 1 is necessary for automatic correction, see comment here https://www.reddit.com/r/btrfs/comments/jm9sdh/how_good_btrfs_really_is/gau3d4f/?utm_source=reddit&utm_medium=web2x&context=3 this is the doubt I have, should I divide my SSD and use RAID 1 for automatic correction?

Answer (score 3):

No, you do not need RAID 1 to use btrfs. Btrfs works just fine with one drive.

Right now I'm only using one drive, but I've also used btrfs successfully with two drives; RAID 1 for metadata and RAID 0 for data.